# Importing a CSV file to phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, csv, phpmyadmin

I am trying to import some data to a phpmyadmin table using a CSV file, but it fails, giving me diferent types of errors at any change I do to import them.

I am using latin1_spanish_ci for the phpmyadmin table and Windows-1252 (which I have read that contains latin1) for the CSV file.

In the phpmyadmin options, I have choosen the following (sorry for the language of the screenshot):

[image: Phpmyadmin screenshot]

Whith these options, I am getting the following error message: "this plugin does not support compressed imports"

Comment: This still happens nearly 2 years on.